# Wrong approach to finding the rational canonical form of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I'm trying to solve for the rational canonical form of the following matrix, but I think I missing something silly.

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}3&2&34 \\ 4&11&5\\5&3&6\end{bmatrix}$$

My approach was to find the characteristic polynomial by computing $det(xI-A)$, which yields: $c_A(x)= x^3-20x^2-76x+1307$.

I then wanted to find the roots (this is over $\mathbb{Q}$) so that I could see what options there might be for the minimal polynomial. I figured that since it has at most $3$ distinct roots, then I need to solve for the $c_i$ in the following equation: $(x-c_1)(x-c_2)(x-c_3)=c_A(x)$.

Is this the way to go about this, generally? Or am I missing something that allows me to identify the roots or solve this more easily?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that you've got all the linear algebra parts right so far! so this is "just" a question about high-school algebra. Typical starting approaches for trying to factor cubic (or higher-degree) polynomials are: try divisors of the constant term (the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) and do polynomial division once you've found one; or calculate the greatest common divisor of the polynomial and its derivative, which will determine any multiple roots the polynomial has.

Comment: You wrote the polynomial wrong, it is the opposite

Comment: @Anon You might like to check the [Eisenstein criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion).

Comment: @Anon The constant term in your characteristic polynomial is wrong, it should be 1307 instead of 130

Comment: @Anon To see that this polynomial does not factor over the rationals, it suffices to apply the [rational roots theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), noting that 1307 is prime.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks - so that means that the rational canonical form is just the one block determined by this polynomial, correct? (i.e. - this is the minimal polynomial too). Fixed the typo in the question.

Comment: @Anon Yes that’s right

Answer (score -1):

The rational canonical form is just the Campanion Matrix of the Characteristic polynomial that is obtained. Hence the RCF is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&-1307\\
1&0&76\\
0&1&20\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: The RCF written above is correct. It’s given by the invariant factors of the Characteristic polynomial. Since it’s irreducible we get the RCF given above.